# Gradle Plugin Development: Idiomatic way of resolving tool artefacts

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Complete noob with developing Gradle plugins.

I am working on a plugin for a bespoke artefact packaging tool. The tool is available as a fat jar in a maven repository. There are more than 1 type of tool to do the job so the plugin needs to figure out which one it needs and add a resolution step to task graph.

I think I need to:

1. Create a configuration for the plugin ("pluginXTools")
2. Figure out which artefact I need and add it in `DependencyResolutionListener::beforeResolve`
3. In my plugins packaging task add a dependency on the resolution step.

How do I wire up artefact resolution to my task so that it is part of the build graph ? Could someone show me the skeleton for what I am trying to achieve

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.query.ArtifactResolutionQuery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked in Gradle slack and looked at some existing plugins. The convention for resolving tool dependencies in Gradle is to use the plugin API to register a hidden configuration with the required dependencies.

The following Kotlin snippet shows what one would need to register a configuration for a particular tool:

```
project.configurations.create("someInternalConfigName").apply {
      isVisible = false
      isTransitive = false
      description = "My internal config for resolving tool"
      defaultDependencies { deps ->
        deps.add(
          project.dependencies.create("my.compiler:the-compiler:1.2.3")
        )
      }
    }
```

During task execution you can do something along the lines of:

```
  private fun resolveCompilerTool(task: Task): URL =
    task.project.configurations.getAt("someInternalConfigName").let {
      it.resolve()
      assert(it.files.size == 1) { "expect a single dependency file" }
      it.files.first().toURI().toURL()
    }
```